# Download all files in Amazon S3 bucket to the client computer using .Net c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a requirement to download all files in a given S3 bucket with a single button click. There are few options that I can think of to do this but want to know what the best and cost effective way to do this. The entire content can be up to 2 Gigs.

**Option 1:** Download each file into a temporary folder on the web server, zip the folder and download the zip file.

**Option 2:** Using Amazon EC2 to zip it and put it back to the S3 bucket and download the zip file. There may be a way to download directly instead of putting it back to s3. I don't know how to do this now but I can do a little research. Some people recommend using AWS Fargate instead of EC2 as EC2 can be more expensive.

Any cost effective and best practice recommendation is appreciated.

Update: Currently there are only less than a hundred users in my web site. Each user requests documents once or twice a month. Files will be downloaded only once and deleted. The documents can range from a few megabytes to a couple gigabytes. Currently users can download one file at a time with a button click. The request I have is - when a user has a 100 files and wanted to download all, he/she should be able to download with a single button click.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clearly define "best" (other than "cost effective" which you've already mentioned)? What are your criteria?

Comment: Who would be doing this? Is it just you, or is it users of your web application? Are the files continuously updated, or fairly static? (For example, if only a few files change, and you download often, there is no need to re-download ALL the files again.) Cost would be the same with any option, since bandwidth is likely to be the biggest expense, and compute is rather low-cost. It might even be suitable for Lambda + EFS.

Comment: John and ADyson. Thank you for your response. I updated my question. I am looking into Lambda + EFS documentation since I don't know much about that.